# Responsive.css not working when getting header with javascript

Tags: html, css

I have been programming a website from a template for a few months now. The website has 3 languages so to simplify I decided to unify the headers and footers using a javascript script. Everything is perfect! Except when I open the website on mobile because the responsive.css does not open. Does anyone know a way to make the responsive.css work in the header so that for example the change in the navigation bar works correctly? Thank you very much.

Here my HTML code with the header and footer linked

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
    ================================================== -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>112-OPS</title>

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
    ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,300i,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Favicon
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../assets/img/logopeque.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../assets/img/logopeque.png">

    <!-- Stylesheets
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=1.10" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../assets/css/style.css?v=1.10" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/css/responsive.css?v=1.10" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.html"); 
        $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="header"></div>


    <div id="footer"></div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.countTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.shuffle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/script.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

So for example this is the structure of my header.html file

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
    <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation">
        <div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 30px">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="agency-navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>   
    </nav><!-- /.site-navigation -->
    <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
               
                <a href="https://112ops.cat/eng/index.html"class="site-title"><span>112</span>-OPS</a>

            </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="agency-navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class="active"><a href="https://112ops.cat/eng/index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">The Group<i class="fa fa-caret-down hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                          <li><a href="normativa.html">Regulations</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/eng/pilotlist.php">Pilot List</a></li>
                          <li><a href="https://wiki.es.ivao.aero/shelves/ops-especiales">Training</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Operations<i class="fa fa-caret-down hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                          
                          <li><a href="/eng/flightlog.php">Last Flights</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/eng/reporte.php">Report a flight</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    
                    <li><a href="/eng/registro.php">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/eng/contacto.html">Contact</a></li>


                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Language<i class="fa fa-caret-down hidden-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                            <li><a href="/ca/index.html"><img src="../assets/img/senyera.png" alt="Senyera" width="22px" height="15px"> Català</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/es/index.html"><img src="../assets/img/espana.png" alt="Espana" width="22px" height="15px"> Castellano </a></li>
                            <li><a href="/eng/index.html"><img src="../assets/img/british.png" alt="English" width="22px" height="15px"> English </a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>   
    </nav><!-- /.site-navigation -->
</header><!-- /#mastheaed -->
```

In the template i have a bootstrap.css file and a responsive.css file that should do the work but when i use the script to link the header or the footer the website works perfectly on mobile excepting the header and the footer that are not responsive anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: In order to find out what the problem is and help people to help you it would be good to remove as much code as possible from your example while still retaining the problem. If the file is not loading from the server to the mobile it may be due to the phone caching an old version of the file. Sometimes you have to clear the cache and then it works.